# Сортировка коллекции по факту другой сортировки

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, коллекции

Имеется `HashMap<String,Integer[]>` В массиве `Integer` три числа.

Суть в том, что необходимо отсортировать коллекцию по значению 2-го числа из массива `Integer`.

Наверное можно как-то использовать компаратор в `Collections.sort`, но я так и не понял как.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если обратите внимание, у `Collections.sort` первый аргумент - `List`, так что такой финт не пройдет

Можно так:

```
HashMap<String, Integer[]> hm = new HashMap<>();
//...fill map   
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer[]>> sortedList = hm.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.getValue()[1], o2.getValue()[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**UPD**

Без стримов и лямбд:

```
HashMap<String, Integer[]> hm = new HashMap<>();
//...fill map   
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer[]>> entryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer[]>>();
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer[]> e : hm.entrySet()){
    entryList.add(e);
}
Collections.sort(entryList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer[]>>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer[]> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer[]> o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getValue()[1], o2.getValue()[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: @I.Perevoz, обновил ответ

Comment: И вновь спасибо за ответ. Если Вас не затруднит, объясните пожалуйста, каким образом в лямбде копилятор понимает что из entrySet'a он должен получить именно 2 разных  Integer'a следующих друг за другом и сортировать именно по возрастанию?

Comment: В лямбде он получает два разных `Map.Entry`, а не 2 разных `Integer`. В данном случае лямбда-выражение - это тот же анонимный компаратор, написанный в примере без лямбд, в этом компараторе всего один метод, который принимает два значения `Map.Entry`. Так вот тут лямбда является просто краткой записью такого анонимного класса. А как сортировать это определяет уже тело лямбды, и там используется `Integer.compare` с порядком аргументов для сортировки по возрастанию (сперва `o1`, затем `o2`)

Comment: т.е. как я понимаю сам компаратор занимается проходом по листу и перестановкой (сортировкой) в соответствии с возвр. значением `Integer.compare`?

Comment: @I.Perevoz, нет, проходом по листу занимается `stream`. После `stream` мы устанавливаем цепочку операций, которую нужно применить в каждому элементу. (это не относится к особым операциям, вроде `sorted`, `limit`).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подсказки.